Choosing Model with Similar Accuracy but Different Numbers of Variables
I have developed machine learning model (XGBClassifier) using different sets of variables, and both sets achieve an accuracy score of around 80%. However, one model uses 17 variables, while the other model uses 18 variables. I'm unsure which model to choose for deployment. Here are some factors I'm considering:

Interpretability: I understand that simpler models with fewer variables are generally preferred for ease of interpretation. Does this mean I should favor the model with 17 variables?

Overfitting: Would the model with 18 variables be more prone to overfitting due to its higher complexity, even though using both variables sets have similar accuracy scores?

Computational Efficiency: Would the model with fewer variables (17) be more computationally efficient in terms of training and prediction time?

Feature Importance: How can I assess the importance of the additional variable in the model with 18 variables? Is there a way to determine whether it provides meaningful insights or improves performance?

Data Quality: Should I consider the quality and dimensionality of my dataset in making this decision? Are there any risks associated with adding an extra variable, such as increased susceptibility to noise or overfitting?

Information: Does more variables gives the model more information, which leads to better decision?

Consideration: I'm on Kaggle Private Competition, so evaluation is considered more.


Given these considerations, how should I approach the decision of choosing between these two sets with similar accuracy but different numbers of variables? Are there any best practices or guidelines I should follow in such cases?
Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

"The best model is no model" - If your problem can be solved without using a model then do this in this way, if you can't - then use the simplest model which serves your goal - because this will ensure your model is learning (or at most able to learn) that information which matters.

Interpretability: Yes, you should favor the model with 17 variables.

Overfitting: Yes, larger model is more prone to overfit. The unnecessary variables don't serve any real benefit.

Computational Efficiency: The smaller the model, the more computationally efficient it is.

Feature Importance: See here How to get feature importance in xgboost?

Data Quality: You should consider the quality and dimensionality of the dataset in making this decision. Take decision which favors the validation performance.

Information: In general, more variable means more variability is learnt. Variance doesn't necessarily mean information. It can be noise as well. Noise is what doesn't help your model in making decision. For example, in an eye detection model iris color can be treated as noise, but for an iris recognition biometric system it is not. Making your model to learn noise will hurt the performance. Because if you do so your model will also try to find features which are not really necessary, and even worse the model may become confused if it doesn't find those (unnecessary) features in the test data in its expected way.

Consideration: Yes, evaluation is considered more.


